# How to hide all the div while showing the one which is clicked, in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, toggle

I'm generating some identical div through a list. Below is the sample code.

I'm toggling this div

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showKitten: false };
  handleToggleKitten = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      showKitten: !prevState.showKitten,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <About
        data={datalist}
        showKitten={this.state.showKitten}
        handleToggleKitten={this.handleToggleKitten}
      />
    );
  }
}

const About = ({ datalist, showKitten, handletogglekitten }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {datalist.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div onClick={handletogglekitten} />
            showKitten ? <div /> : null
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have defined tooglefunction and the flag state variable in parent and passing them to children and in children component, I'm creating this divs by iterating over a list. Right now I am able to achieve the toggle functionality for the individual div set but **I want to hide all the div and show the one which is clicked.**

Comment: The most easy way would be to hide them with CSS selected by their parent component and simply toggling the class to show and hide the children div ithout the need to write a complicated function for it.

Comment: Can you please share your parent component(where you iterating) code?

Comment: @RajaJaganathan I have updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: @MichelEngelen  With css i will have the same issue, all the child component have the same class but only _this_ component will get effected by click. i need to hide other as well. I have also updated the code, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the index value. Here's a working example.

```
const datalist = ["cat 1", "cat 2", "cat 3"];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { showKittenIndex: null };

  render() {
    return (
      <About
        datalist={datalist}
        showKittenIndex={this.state.showKittenIndex}
        toggleKitten={index => this.setState({ showKittenIndex: index })}
      />
    );
  }
}

const About = ({ datalist, showKittenIndex, toggleKitten }) => (
  <div className="about">
    {datalist.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <button onClick={() => toggleKitten(index)}>toggle {index}</button>
        {showKittenIndex === index && <div>{item}</div>}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Output is similar as my code. I want to hide all other index and show the one which is clicked. is it possible to use another flag variable for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar approach than @Kunukn.

But I don't see the need to wrap it in a functional component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const elements = ['DIV #1', 'DIV #2', 'DIV #3', 'DIV #4', 'DIV #5', 'DIV #6'];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeElement: null,
      allElements: elements,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <About
        elements={this.state.allElements}
        showIndex={this.state.activeElement}
        toggleIndex={index => this.setState({ activeElement: index })}
      />
    );
  }
}

const About = ({ elements, showIndex, toggleIndex }) => (
  <div className="about">
    {elements.map((element, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <div onClick={() => toggleIndex(index)}>toggleIndex {index}</div>
        {showIndex === index && <div>{element}</div>}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

I did write a little `clickHandler` ... I know that it is not needed at the moment, but when you would want to alter the data received with the click-event this could be handled there as well.

---

**EDIT**

According to the comment I improved the code a bit by making a `functional component` showing the `DIV`s. I did also dismiss the `clickHandler()` function.

Comment: Actually the functional component("About") is my main component. I just showed you the skeleton of my component. "About" Component was stateless and i created a parent of that stateless component because i need  to do some enhancement which is not possible without capturing state.

Comment: Well, you can easily adapt this with a functional component as base for the `About` ... I will rewrite it a bit and edit my answer in some minutes